# Will "deleting" an icon from the home-screen only delete the icon, or also uninstall the app?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, app-icons

I want to remove the icon for McAfee Security, without uninstalling the application.

[image: mcAfee Icon]

I long-press and drag the McAfee icon, but there's only "delete" option at the top of the screen:

[image: mid-drag]

Then, there's a prompt:

[image: prompt asking if user wants to delete the app]

I am not getting separate options:

- remove icon
- uninstall app

I can't tell if its going to delete the icon/shortcut only, or also uninstall the application.

Will "deleting" an icon from the home-screen uninstall the associated app?

Comment: It's been a while, but it'd be better if you could also [edit] & mention the device model, Android version, and whether this is a stock/3rd-party home screen since Firelord's answer is a big possibility due to the "many flavors" of Android.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting an icon usually only removes the icon, not the app itself. However, if your launcher's home screen is merged with app drawer of the launcher, then it is likely it would delete the app. In the former case, launchers know that it is just the icon that is to be removed, so no user approval in the form of dialog is required.

I suggest you try to find it out on your own what actually would happen. Install a fairly harmless app, such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera), and try to remove its icon. You would have your answer right away.

Comment: The link was the first one that I found when looking for open source apps. One can install just about any app for the sake of testing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in home screen and you **remove** the icon, it won't uninstall the application. It is just a mere shortcut for the app. But if you **delete** the application then it will be uninstalled from your phone.

Comment: IF you look at the screen capture I posted you will see that there are not two options: `remove` and `delete`. After long-pressing the icon there is only ***ONE*** option, which is `delete`.